# Rotate element 180 degrees on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm looking to rotate an image 180 degrees when the user scrolls down on a web page. The rotation should happen during the time the image is visible in the viewport and the image should rotate back to its original positon when the user scrolls back up.

I got it working for the most part, but sometimes the rotation stops at seemingly random value below 180 degrees. I can't figure out why and want to make sure the image always rotates to 180.

```js
var iconRotate = $('.icon-rotate img');
if (iconRotate.length != 0) {
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  var page = window.pageYOffset,
  inner = window.innerHeight,
  result = (180 * page / (inner/3)); 

  if (result < 180) {
      console.log(result);
   iconRotate.css({transform: 'rotate(-' + result + 'deg)'});
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.icon-rotate {
  width:300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-rotate">
  <img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/6324fd64b78c316379713480b8e44d29/tumblr_nd1rffWqEa1ryzl2ko1_1280.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really do a percentage based on scroll and the most you can scroll.

```js
var iconRotate = $('.icon-rotate img');
if (iconRotate.length != 0) {
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
  maxScroll = $(document).height()-$(window).height();
  iconRotate.css({transform: 'rotate(-' + (180 * scroll/maxScroll) + 'deg)'});
 });
}
```

```css
.icon-rotate {
  width:300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-rotate">
  <img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/6324fd64b78c316379713480b8e44d29/tumblr_nd1rffWqEa1ryzl2ko1_1280.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. this works in that it stops rotating at 180 degrees when the bottom of the page is reached. however, the image I want to rotate is on very long page. the user never gets to see the full rotation that way. the image should turn on its head while it is visible to the user.

I've managed to speed up the rotation in my example using this line: 

`result = (180 * page / (inner/3));`

this way the image is rotated fully before the bottom of the page is reached. however I think this leads to the image sometimes being not fully rotated and stopping at some value like 176 degrees.